# ISS Interim Control Module Specifications

Tags: iss

Anybody have a copy of the specifications for the Interim Control Module?  Particularly interested in mass, either dry or fully loaded...or both!

Answer (score 7):

A problem with getting detailed info on the ICM is that it was based on a classified spacecraft. Even when I worked at JSC, details were scant.

Here is the best info I've seen in the wild, from the January 20, 1997 issue of [Aviation Week](http://archive.aviationweek.com).  I can't give a direct link since it's behind a paywall, but here is an excerpt (sorry that it's an image, that is how the archives are stored).

[image]

The April 14, 1997 issue contained a schematic drawing of the ICM docked to the proto-ISS. At this point the ISS (exclusive of the ICM) consisted of Node 1, the FGB, three conical Pressurized Mating Adaptors, and the Z1 truss segment.  A Soyuz is shown docked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Any guesses out there as to what four 15-foot wide, 5 foot tall isogrid panels would weigh?  The TLD/ICM's core structure was made up of four isogrid (like Delta tank) panels.

Comment: That is way smaller than I ever envisioned from reading about it over the years.  Interesting, thanks for that one!

Comment: Using the ISOGRID Design Handbook from the NASA Reports Server (Report CR 124075) I was able to come up with a weight of 2182 pounds for the panels.  THIS IS A ROM ESTIMATE, if not an outright SWAG, but is a starting point for estimating the ICM's mass.  Note that ISOGRID panels use triangular webs while the TLD/ICM used square webs, but still should be in the ballpark